# liquibase generateChangeLog command skips tables

Tags: oracle, liquibase

`Liquibase` `generateChangeLog` doesn't generate changesets for all the tables in the schema. Out of the 169 tables in the schema I get changesets for only 152. I couldn't find any similar issues posted online. Has anybody else faced a similar issue. What could be causing such a behaviour ?

I am using oracle. Here are a few examples of the table names.

DISPLAY_PROPERTY

EXTERNAL_TRADE

EXTERNAL_TRADE_AUDIT

QUOTE_SPECIFICATION

QUOTE_SPECIFICATION_ACCOUNT

QUOTE_SPECIFICATION_ATTRIBUTE

QUOTE_SPECIFICATION_PRICING

V_SYMBOL

Comment: What are the names of the tables that are skipped? Might it be possible that they look like 'system' tables? Also, it would be helpful to know what dbms is being used.

Comment: My mistake, updated the question.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately obvious, so my only suggestion is to run the command with --logLevel=debug and examine that output. It may reveal the reason.

Comment: I did that, it outputs only a few lines and about four queries. So started looking a the liquibase source code. I'll have to spend some more time on it, may be that'll yield something. Thankyou for the response.

Comment: can u post your .xml file here ? atleast show us the code for the tables which has executed the statements and the code for the tables which has not executed .. do u see the entry in the databasechangelog tables ?